# Reuse picture box to open links

Tags: c#

I am making an application where I have pictureboxes with icons in them. When you click the picturebox, it pulls you to a website. I reuse the picturebox 50+ times, and it seems like there has to be a better way to code it. Currently, I have a event trigger on each picture box to open up the site, but that seems like I am making way to much work for myself.

Currently I am doing it something like this:

```
 private void CreditPic1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("website");
        }
        private void CreditPic2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("website");
```

**Updated error:**

> Error 1   'Creditr.Form1' does not contain a definition for
>   'CreditPic1_Click' and no extension method 'CreditPic1_Click'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Creditr.Form1' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Current Code:**

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EventHandler openwebsite = new EventHandler(delegate { System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Credits"); });
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c.Name.StartsWith("CreditPic"))
                {
                    c.Click += openwebsite;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of this:

```
EventHandler openwebsite = new EventHandler(delegate { System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("website"); });
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if(c.Name.StartsWith("CreditPic")) {
        c.Click += openwebsite;
    }
}
```

Directly after your form's `InitializeComponent();` in its constructor.

It should iterate through every control in your form and if a control's name starts with 'CreditPic' it will attach the delegate `openwebsite` to its `Click` event.

The advantage to doing this as opposed to adding a new event handler through the form viewer in Visual Studio, or adding one manually (See Grantly's answer) is that this method of adding event handlers is dynamic meaning every time you delete or add a new 'CreditPic' picture box you wont need to modify your code, it will automatically add the event on runtime (assuming the control's name begins with 'CreditPic').

---

This will only work on controls that are direct children of the form. To circumvent this you can use a stack to push a control's children to the stack while you're iterating it:

```
EventHandler opengoogle = new EventHandler(delegate { System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com"); });

Stack<Control> Controls = new Stack<Control>();
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) Controls.Push(c);
do
{
    Control c = Controls.Pop();

    if (c.Name.StartsWith("GooglePic"))
        c.Click += opengoogle;

    foreach (Control nc in c.Controls)
        Controls.Push(nc);
} while (Controls.Count > 0);
```

Comment: Awesome, this looks like the best route to take. Thanks for the help and support!

Comment: I think I am missing something basic. I added in your code, and did a test. When I click on the picturebox labled 'CreditPic1', nothing at all happens. (no errors). I am getting an error when I remove the old click_events however. I updated top post with that error.

Comment: Visual Studio for some reason doesn't think to automatically remove events once you've deleted its method in the code. You need to click on the control in the form view, then click on the lightening bolt in the control's properties window, then find the 'Click' action and clear it.

Comment: Alright, that error is gone, back to the original - Clicking the picturebox does nothing, like the event is not triggering.

Comment: Have you made sure to put the code directly after `InitializeComponent();`? Otherwise none of the controls will have been added to the Form yet.

Comment: Since this is a more specific issue and we might clog up the comments I've created a room for us to talk about it further, [right here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157624/room-for-alphadelta-and-dwb).

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically add the event handlers to each instance of the PictureBox, so that they point to the same function when the event fires, like this

```
CreditPic1.Click += new EventHandler(YourNewFunctionName);
CreditPic2.Click += new EventHandler(YourNewFunctionName);
```

...
Even hardcoding this is not too bad, or you could use some sort of Reflection to loop through all the PictureBoxes...(Or loop through all the controls on the form)